# fixed header and scrollable body in table in html angular

Tags: html, angular

In Angular i have a table and it should be scrollable. But header should be fixed. but while scrolling header is not fixed. please help

Comment: `fixed-header`  is it any directive?

Comment: i have seen in some answer so added that but no change

Comment: i think issue is because i have added scroll for the entire div<>; but tried adding scroll for body also it didnt work

Comment: If your table body has a fixed height it's easy: thead, tbody { display: block;}tbody { overflow-y: scroll; height: 100px;}
If not, the only thing I know can work is duplicate the table, one in a fixed div with a height,e.g. 1.5rem  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#fixed-top, and in a div that will see under the "fixed"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the requirement seems to be you want a scrollable table body. Not sure if angular could makes things different anyhow in this case.
Just to be sure, please see the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/hh6etg6s/ if this serves the purpose.

```
.tablediv {
  padding:20px;
}
table ,tr td{
    border:1px solid red
}
tbody {
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;/* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}
thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, remove it from thead width */
}
table {
    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: Would appreciate if you would accept the answer too.

Comment: i have given fixed height for the table but when the result is only one then it seems like some blank space i mean the height of the table is not adjusting automatically. How to achieve that.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to suit as per your requirement https://jsfiddle.net/hh6etg6s/2/. And I again request you to please acknowledge the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: Could you please help this post also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903324/page-not-scrolling-to-top-while-navigating-in-angular

Answer (score 2):

Check out this post from angularjswiki:
https://www.angularjswiki.com/material/mat-table-fixed-sticky-header/

Taken from there:

> In Angular, To create a `mat-table` with fixed header and scrollable body, we have to add `sticky` input to the `matHeaderRowDef`.

Answer (score 1):

Have two instances of your table in your HTML in separate divs. In the top container, hide your body. In your bottom container hide your headers. Do this with visibility: collapse;

If you need to hide the scrollbars:

[Hide Scroll Bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqLmE.png)