# Page not scrolling to top while navigating in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

In my app while routing urls the page which loads is not scrolling to top automatically. It remains the same position as the previous screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `app component`:
**TS:**

```
import { Router ,NavigationEnd} from '@angular/router';
export class AppComponent{
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
      })
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: do you import this to your app `import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: I have imported router and no error been seen in console

Comment: `import { Router ,NavigationEnd} from '@angular/router';`

Comment: Try and put the `window.scrollTo` in a `setTimeout(() => ...)`

Comment: import { Router, ActivatedRoute,NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

Comment: added set timeout also; seems like the page is scrolling but not upto the top

Comment: check if you dont have any margin/padding to top

Comment: I can see the scrollbar position moving up while navigating but not reaching the top most.

Comment: I have given some top margins but without that the UI of the screen will break

Comment: Can you please share your code where in UI is breaking if top margins are avoided. A fiddle will be much appreciated.

Comment: when I remove the top margin the heading space will be reduced from top fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/rubytat/5p1q2bdz/13/      It is like

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router'; 
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id, 
    selector: ‘my-app’,
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})

export class AppComponent {
    routerSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
            .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .subscribe(event => {
                document.body.scrollTop = 0;
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

remove `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from app.component.html